Authenticating to Azure application with JMeter
I am following the Blog Authenticating to Azure AD with JMeter without plugins:
But I always got the below error:
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS900144: The
 request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'. Trace
 ID: 93481b5XXXXX6337da00 Correlation ID:
 b7d28456-9a58-4XXXXXXXXX6939710 Timestamp: 2024-09-13
 09:50:09Z","error_codes":[900144],"timestamp":"2024-09-13
 09:50:09Z","trace_id":"93481b52XXXXXXX-ca5e6337da00","correlation_id":"b7d28456-9a58-4XXXXXXXX939710","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=900144"}

My setting for the JMeter like below:






I think you need to untick this Use multipart/form-data box:

Going forward instead of "following" random blogs I would rather suggest recording your test scenario and performing correlation yourself as the number and the nature of parameters might differ depending on the implementation of external authentication mechanism, moreover there is Correlation Recorder Plugin which is capable of automatically detecting and handling dynamic values.

untick this Use multipart/form-data works for me. Thanks.
